# How to tell if the value of a map is undefined in Go?

Tags: go, undefined

Suppose I have a map like:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{}
```

Now I get a string `"a"`, I want to know if there's value in `m["a"]`, how can I tell?

As I can see now, `m["a"]` is never `nil`, so I can't compare it to nil to see if there's anything. Also, there's not a keyword named `undefined` to do that..

Answer (score 4):

map access returns two values, the second one being a boolean telling you if there's a value.

You can use this standard idiom :

```
if elm, ok := m["a"]; ok {
    // there's an element
} else {
    // no element
}
```

[Documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps)